# Variable replacement inside of GET request

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am working with a web API to retrieve system data.  The line in question looks like this:

```
response = requests.get('https://api.company.com/api/v0/devices/[serial]/switchPorts', headers=headers)
```

[serial] has to replaced with a valid serial number for the given piece of equipment I am querying.

It works perfectly fine when I use any valid serial number.

However, I have hundreds of items to query, so I do not want to change [serial] manually for each piece of equipment.

Using another supplied API, I have generated a set() of all serial numbers
named: serials()

What I want to do is say:

```
for serial in serials:
    response = requests.get('https://api.company.com/api/v0/devices/%var/switchPorts', headers=headers)
```

where %var receives each serial number so I can iterate over the list of serials in a loop.

Is there a way to replace [serial] with a variable that will receive, at each iteration, the current value of 'serial' and run that API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
for serial in serials:
    response = requests.get('https://api.company.com/api/v0/devices/{0}/switchPorts'.format(serial), headers=headers)
```

Or **[f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)**

**Ex:**

```
for serial in serials:
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.company.com/api/v0/devices/{serial}/switchPorts', headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just construct the string ahead of time, then pass it to the request, like this:

```
for serial in serials:
  url = 'https://api.company.com/api/v0/devices/' + serial + '/switchPorts'
  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I also just like the practice of creating the url for any network request before the actual request.